# Couldn't set up a simple scala project

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbteclipse

I have not code for a few years and now trying to get back into the game. I am trying to set up a very simple scala project **HelloWorld** and getting the following error message when I try to compile from sbt console. I was adding **sbteclipse** plugin to generate eclipse project setting.

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;4.0.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.typesafe.sbteclipse:sbteclipse-plugin:4.0.0 (scalaVersion=2.11, sbtVersion=0.13)
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      com.typesafe.sbteclipse:sbteclipse-plugin:4.0.0 (scalaVersion=2.11, sbtVersion=0.13) (/Users/michael/Development/Scala-Testings/HelloWorld/project/plugins.sbt#L3-4)
[warn]        +- default:helloworld-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.11, sbtVersion=0.13)
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;4.0.0: not found
```

I am on macOS Sierra with **scala version 2.11.8** and **sbt 0.13.12** installed from brew.

Project Directory Structure

```
src
+- main
   +- scala
      +- HelloWorld.scala
project
+- plugins.sbt
build.sbt
```

Content of build.sbt

```
name := "HelloWorld"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
```

Content of plugins.sbt

```
logLevel := Level.Warn

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")
```

Content of HelloWorld.scala

```
object HelloWorld extends App {
    def main (args Array[String]) : Unit = {
        println ("HelloWorld!")
    }
}
```

Comment: WFM. eclipse command runs. Is that good news or bad news? You will find two errors in your code when sbt finally tries to compile it.

Comment: does it need a resolver? I would recommend to install activator and the run `activator new`: http://www.lightbend.com/community/core-tools/activator-and-sbt

Comment: Yeah, I got it working by removing
    addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")
from project_folder/project/plugins.sbt
and putting in ~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/plugins.sbt file.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is has to do with sbt version 0.13.12 which is compiled with Scala version 2.10.x while I have Scala 2.11.8 installed.

I got it working by removing

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")
```

from

```
project_folder/project/plugins.sbt
```

and putting in

```
~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/plugins.sbt file.
```